# Javascript OOP: loosing "this" and take last object created instead (jsfiddle sample)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, oop, jsfiddle

here is the code:
http://jsfiddle.net/j5LtR/6/

this code is a confirm popin message,
on click on "click here" link, it create a new confirm popin message
it works well until 2 Object of this popin are created.

trouble:
the close button on header bar dont act as it should:
it close last opened confirm popin instead of "this" opened confirm popin

to test it in the jsfiddle click 2 times on "click here !!" link, this will create 2 popin (you can move them case they will be superposed)

the bug seem to be there:

```
    //close btn
    $('<a>',{
        class   : 'close',
        text    : 'X',
        title   : 'close',
        click   : function()
                    {      
                        /*=============close btn !!!!=================*/
                        alert('CLOSE !');
                        _that.close();
                    }
```

but i do almost samething in the inherit class, and it works ....

```
nBtn=$('<a>',{
    class   : 'btn-n',
    text    : 'no',
    title   : 'no button',
    click   : function()
                {
                    /*=============close btn !!!!=================*/
                    alert('NO !');                          
                    _that.close();
                }
    });
```

if someone have an idea why the top close button act like that, it could help me, thanks !

Comment: Where is `_that` set? What is the closure you're generating over it?

Comment: _that=this;
full code is there http://jsfiddle.net/j5LtR/6/

Comment: That's great, but what is `this`, it's not the element, and your code is a mess and hard to follow.

Comment: can you explain me why you find it hard to follow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case is an example that show how global variables are bad. Here's you're fix:

```
var _that=this;
```

In your `setPanel()` function -> http://jsfiddle.net/j5LtR/7/

Note that you should always use `var`.

**Details**: while defining `_that = this;`, you overwrite existing definition of `_that` in the whole JS application each time this instruction is executed, whereas `var _that = this;` will restrict `_that` in the current scope (~parent function and "sub-functions" of this one).

Comment: THX, i don't believe i forget to declare it !
anyway thanks a lot was looking anywhere but not where i should :P

btw do find this code hard to follow as adeneo said ?